# Running Unreached code in C

Tags: c, stack

Below is the a sample C Program which provides the output followed after the program

```
#include<stdio.h>
void newfunc(int n);
int main(void)
{
    newfunc(2);
    return 0;
}
void newfunc(int n)
{
    printf("\n%d",n);
    if(n<50)
    {
        newfunc(2*n);
        printf("\n%d",n);
    }
}
```

produces output

```
2
4
8
16
32
64
32
16
8
4
2
```

But according to the code, it seems that after the function call in line 13, the next    `printf` is  not called. And the output seems unnatural. I searched the internet and found something about stacks. Can someone elaborate why this happens?

Comment: What's unnatural about it?  `newfunc(64)` prints 64.  `newfunc(32)` prints 32, then calls `newfunc(2*32)`, then prints 32.  Which means it prints 32, then 64, then 32....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic recursive call.

First, notice that for values of `n` less than 50 your function will print `n` twice, and for other values of `n` it will print only once. That agrees with your output,so the only thing to figure out here is the order...

Second notice that the output for `n*2` should come *between* the first and second line of output from `n` (for `n < 50`), because you make the recursive call *in between* the two `printf`s. Well, that *also* agrees with your output.

This is as expected.

The part you found on the internet about stacks is referring to the call stack. In order to return from a function the program has to keep track of where it was when the function was called. This information is written to 'end' of a special part of memory called the "call stack" or "execution stack"; and it is taken off of the stack (meaning that the 'end' is moved when the function returns). Call parameters are also recorded on the stack.

This kind of stacking is essential to recursion.

So, when you call `newfunc(2)` the program records that it was on line 5, then jumps to the beginning of `newfunc` on line 8. The stack looks (notionally) like:

```
line 5, n=2
```

When it gets to line 13, it calls new function again, making the stack

```
line 5, n=2; line 13, n=4
```

This goes on several times until the stack looks like

```
line 5, n=2; line 13, n=4; line 13, n=8; line 13, n=16; line 13, n=32; line 13, n=64
```

when the if fails and `newfunc` returns poping the stack and resuming execution after line 13 (because that is what we got off the stack) making the stack

```
line 5, n=2; line 13, n=4; line 13, n=8; line 13, n=16; line 13, n=32
```

when we run `printf` and pop the stack as we return to line 13 (what we got when we popped, right>) so that the stack is

```
line 5, n=2; line 13, n=4; line 13, n=8; line 13, n=16;
```

and so on while it unwinds the whole call stack.

A couple of final details: the stack notionally grows "up" so we often write it as

```
line 13, n=32
line 13, n=16
line 13, n=8 
line 13, n=4 
line 5, n=2
```

and the exact format of the stuff of the stack depends on the architecture of the chip and some decisions made by the OS programmers.

---

BTW--a c program doesn't typically use line numbers to denote "where" it was because lines are not good measures in c (I can write the whole program one one line if I'm silly enough), rather it uses the value of a register on the chip, but that doesn't really affect the explanation here.

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens is, when you call the function in line 13 the code after the function cannot execute at that time, so they are stored in a special place in memory called stacks and they are filled up from bottom so newer codes fill in the top of the stacks. So at the first function call the `printf("\n%d",2)` is added to the stack at the **bottom** and `printf("\n%d",4);` i.e, **2 * n = 2 * 2 = 4**  is added to **top** of the previous stack and when the recursive execution stops.  the stack program from top is executed producing the above complex type of output not predictable to simple analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take it for small value say 10

```
1st call from main         ////returned from newfunc(2)
newfunc(2)             
//inside newfunc(2)
print 2
2<10 (correct)
newfunc(4)  --> on stack print 2  //returned from newfunc(4)
-------------------------------
//inside newfunc(4)
print 4 
4<10
newfunc(8)  --> on stack print 4 //returned from newfunc(8)
---------------------------------
//inside newfunc(8)
print 8
8<10
newfunc(16) --> on stack print 8 //returned from newfunc(16)
---------------------------
//inside newfunc(16)
print 16
16<10 failed
```

so it will `return` to its previous function whichever has called it so it will go on `-->` symbol which is top of stack here for this example and `print` is used to show the `result` on screen

Function sequence is top to down ... I tried to show this in diagram. hope you get it.

here `-->` statement will be executed from bottom to top so the result will be

```
2
4
8
16
8
4
2
```